# iOS7 UITapGestureRecognizer method is not called

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uipickerview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am working on UIPickerView with multi selection in iOS7 and used UITapGestureRecognizer for multi selection.

**In iOS6 its working fine but in iOS7 toggleSelection: (UITapGestureRecognizer) method is not called.**

So Please give me idea or suggestion for resolve this issue.

**Please see my below code.**

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setBounds: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width -20 , 44)];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSelection:)];
        [gestureRecog setDelegate:self];
        gestureRecog.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [gestureRecog.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
//        [singleTapGestureRecognizer.view setTag:row];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecog];
    }

    if ([self.selectedItems indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:row]] != NSNotFound) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    cell.tag = row;

    if (self.flag == 0 ) {
        if (self.arraCountry.count > 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arraCountry objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"name"];
        }
    }
    else if (self.flag == 1) {
        if (self.arraStates.count > 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arraStates objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"name"];
        }
    }
    else if (self.flag == 2) {
        if (self.arrayCity.count > 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arrayCity objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"name"];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
- (void)toggleSelection:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSNumber *row = [NSNumber numberWithInt:recognizer.view.tag];
    NSUInteger index = [self.selectedItems indexOfObject:row];
    if (index != NSNotFound) {
        [self.selectedItems removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    } else {
        [self.selectedItems addObject:row];
        [(UITableViewCell *)(recognizer.view) setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
}
```